# How to use if- else to check the mousehover?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Currently I trying to check the mousehover on the Image, if mouse is pointing on the image then it will take another image to replace the original image

here is my code:

ASPX code:

```
    <img class="xyz" data-alt-src="<%=widget1%>" src="<%=widget1%>"/>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected string widget1
    {
        get
        {
            if (mousehover==true)
            {
                return "Pic/pic1.jpg";
            }
            else{
                return "Pic/pic2.jpg";
            }
        }
    }
```

Jquery:

```
var sourceSwap = function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
            $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
            $this.attr('src', newSource);
        }

    $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function () { 
    var $this = $(this); 
    new Image().src = $this.data('alt-src'); 
    $this.hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not handle the hover event well. Do this;

```
var sourceSwap = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
    }

$('img[data-alt-src]').hover(sourceSwap);
```

Also, place it inside a document ready event to make sure all the dom is fully loaded before attaching the event like this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
.....Your codes here


});
```